# Find all entities of a given type?

Tags: 7, entities

I am working on an admin interface for a module that uses a custom entity type. Is there a function or some way that I can use to find all entities of a given type, so that I can show users a list of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the [`EntityFieldQuery` class](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7):

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
  ->fieldCondition('field_my_field', 'value', 'a_value')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->fieldOrderBy('field_my_field', 'value', 'DESC');

$results = $query->execute();
if (isset($results['node'])) {
  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($results['node']));

  foreach ($nodes as $nid => $node) {
    // Do something with the node object
  }
}
```

The above code loads all node entities with a content type of `article`. It filters on a custom field called `field_my_field` and the `status` property of the node. I only put that in for reference you wouldn't need it to load all nodes without any filters. Same goes for the order by statement.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try the following simple two-liner:

```
$res = (new EntityFieldQuery)->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')->execute(); 
$entities = entity_load('node', array_keys(reset($res)));
```

Or the following one-liner (PHP >= 5.5), ready to use with `drush eval`:

```
print_r((new EntityFieldQuery)->entityCondition("entity_type", "node")->entityCondition("bundle", "page")->execute());
```

To remove them, please check: [Can I delete nodes of a given content type with Drush?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34044/can-i-delete-nodes-of-a-given-content-type-with-drush)