# Can I delete nodes of a given content type with Drush?

Tags: drush

Just wondering if Drush is capable of deleting nodes of a given content type.

Something like: `$ drush delete-node --type=MyContentType`

If not possible, can I create a **method** like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a function like follows:

```
function MYMODULE_delete_all_the_things() {
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery;

  $result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->propertyCondition('type', 'YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE')
    ->execute();

  if (isset($result['node']) && count($result['node'])) {

    $node_ids = array_keys($result['node']);

    node_delete_multiple($node_ids);
  }
}
```

Note - You could also use a simple `SELECT` query, but seeing as you're working with entities it seems more sensible/common-practice to use [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7).

This should also be quite easy to change or add arguments to.  You can also put it in a Drush command quite easily - there's an example for how to do this in the Drush [repository](http://drupalcode.org/project/drush.git/blob/HEAD:/examples/sandwich.drush.inc) (check the Commands section near the bottom).

Comment: I see, it sound like the repository link shows how to properly add a drush method.

Comment: Yup!  The readme has some different ways you can implement them as well!

Answer (score 40):

#### Drush 9

`drush entity:delete node --bundle=my_content_type`

Comment: Best answer nowadays!

Comment: Best answer ! i just tried it .

Answer (score 25):

Install the devel module, and use drush to delete all the nodes,

```
$  drush genc --kill 0 0
```

You can also give a type option,

```
$  drush genc --kill --types=article 0 0
```

Comment: Clever, I like it.

Comment: This works with D8. The `devel_generate` module is included with devel, but needs to be enabled with `drush en devel_generate`  genc is normally used to *create* nodes, so the 0 0 at the end is telling it not to create anything new, and the --kill to remove what's already there.

Answer (score 15):

I guess you can by using the below command

```
drush node_delete <nid>
```

EDIT: Found a module that does something/related to the question

http://drupal.org/project/delete_all

**Usage**

**Drush**

`drush delete-all`

Example: `drush delete-all article`

Comment: I meant to delete all nodes by content type.

Comment: Did you try this module http://drupal.org/project/delete_all

Usage
Drush

drush delete-all

Example: drush delete-all article

Comment: where I can find the drush node_delete <nid> command?

Comment: To save people time, as of Dec 2016, `delete_all` [isn't yet ported to Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2677766), but the genc answer works.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this would work (untested):

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node', '=')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'Announcements')
  ->execute();

$nids = array_keys($entities['node']);

node_delete_multiple($nids);
```

This will find all of the nodes with the content type `Annoucements` using [`EntityFieldQuery()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7).  It then gets all the `$nids` from the result, and deleted them using [`node_delete_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7).

You can take this code, put it in a separate PHP file, and then execute it with `drush scr`.

Using the API will ensure that all of the proper hooks fire.  Among other things, they will also delete the node revisions and field data (and their revisions) so you don't have orphaned data in the database.

Answer (score 5):

There are some good ideas on this thread. If you dont want to do any programming really and want to use Drush you can look at the [Delete All](http://www.drupal.org/project/delete_all) contributed module:

```
Drush
drush delete-all
Example: drush delete-all article

Drush on Drupal 7 version

Delete all nodes, nodes of a specific content type or users.

Examples:
 drush delete-all article             Delect all article nodes.
 drush delete-all all                 Delete nodes of all types.
 drush delete-all --reset             Delete nodes of all types, and reset node, revision and comment counters.
 drush delete-all users               Delete users.

Options:
 --reset                              Reset counter for node, revision and comment tables.
 --roles                              pick roles

Aliases: da
```

Answer (score 3):

VBO has Drush integration.
Create a VBO view of nodes, execute it via Drush (using `drush vbo-execute`), pass the node type as an argument.

Comment: I think that this is what I need.Just 2 questions: Which is the drush method to execute a view?  and Will this method be faster than executing the view in the browser?

Comment: Edited the answer to specify the exact drush command.
And yes, it will be faster because this way the view isn't rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a drush script (let's say it's called "bulk_delete.php" and is placed under the Drupal root folder):

```
#!/usr/bin/env drush

$res = db_delete('node')
  ->condition('type', 'mycontenttype', '=')
  ->execute();

echo "deleted:" . $res;
```

This is absolutely the fastest way to do it: a direct query to the db, using the Drupal's function db_delete

Usage:

```
:~# cd /var/www/www.mysite.com
:~# drush --uri=www.mysite.com scr bulk_delete.php
```

Doc: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_delete/7

Warning: this process does not delete the data of their fields. Anyway the same process can be applied to these fields (looking at the "bundle" column of each field).
For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env drush

$field_tables = array(
  'field_data_field_body',
  'field_data_field_mycoolfield',
  'field_revision_body',
  'field_revision_field_mycoolfield'
);

foreach ($field_tables as $field_table) {
  $res = db_delete($field_table)
    ->condition('bundle', 'mycontenttype', '=')
    ->execute();

  echo "deleted:" . $res . "\n\n";
}
```

Where "mycontenttype" is the one used in the first query.

Comment: Why the condition `'nid' > 5000`?

Comment: it's an example, like the type.

Comment: But the original poster doesn't mention about such a condition, that's why I think the example is irrelevant, thus misleading.

Answer (score 1):

**Drupal 7**

Try the following one-liner, it removes all MyContentType nodes from Drupal:

```
drush eval '$res = (new EntityFieldQuery)->entityCondition("entity_type", "node")->entityCondition('bundle', 'MyContentType')->execute(); entity_delete_multiple("node", array_keys(reset($res)));'
```

Or you can remove all the entities based on the entity type name (e.g. node):

```
drush eval '$res = (new EntityFieldQuery)->entityCondition("entity_type", "node")->execute(); entity_delete_multiple("node", array_keys(reset($res)));'
```

Note: `node` is your entity type name, you can change it if required.

---

If you'll get memory or time out errors, you may add the following sets just before the `$res`:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', -1); ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete all nodes of a particular content type, you may try to run the following command via drush:

```
drush eval '$res = (new EntityFieldQuery)->entityCondition("entity_type", "node")->entityCondition('bundle', 'MyContentType')->execute(); entity_delete_multiple("node", array_keys(reset($res)));'
```

Where MyContentType is your machine Content Type name (e.g. Page).

Answer (score 1):

For individual nodes:

```
$ drush php-eval 'node_delete($node->nid);'
```

> [drush php-eval](https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/core/php-eval/)
>   Evaluate arbitrary php code after bootstrapping Drupal

Comment: Please add some more details to explain your code, without that this may be considered as a low quality answer (and hence it might get deleted via moderation).

Answer (score 1):

Updating the answer provided by @kenorb.

In Drupal 8

```
drush eval '$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->execute(); $storage = Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node'); $e = $storage->loadMultiple($nids); $storage->delete($e);'
```

Comment: drush ev '$type='\''node'\''; entity_delete_multiple($type, \Drupal::entityQuery($type)->execute());'

Comment: To update an existing answer, please drop a comment to suggest an edit.

Answer (score 1):

To help those that find this thread - use the following command to delete all the nodes within a content type - **drush uses bundles now instead of types**:

```
drush genc --kill --bundles=about 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with the devel module as answered at [Can I delete nodes of a given content type with Drush?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34044/can-i-delete-nodes-of-a-given-content-type-with-drush)

Install the devel module, and use drush to delete all the nodes,

$  drush genc --kill 0 0

You can also give a type option,

$  drush genc --kill --types=article 0 0

Answer (score -1):

You can use

`drush node_delete NID` to delete specific node, but if you want to delete all nodes by content type I guess you can create a drush plugin using batch api.

Comment: I can't found the drush node_delete NID command.

Comment: That command doesn't exists