# How can I remove nodes?

Tags: 8, console

How can I remove nodes using Drupal Console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal Console is for creating boilerplate code (also known as scaffolding) rather than for general administration and day-to-day work.  You can see an overview of the features of Drupal Console:

[How does Drupal Console help?](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/about/how-does-drupal-console-help.html)

To delete a node you would be advised to use drush which is a general purpose DRUpal SHell. Drush doesn't have a command to do this out of the box but there are a number of different approaches outlined in this post,
[Can I delete nodes of a given content type with Drush?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34044/can-i-delete-nodes-of-a-given-content-type-with-drush)