# How to delete a node or a list of nodes with Drush?

Tags: 7, nodes, drush

I discovered the [Delete all](https://www.drupal.org/project/delete_all) module which gives you the ability to delete all the nodes of a given content type. However, with this module you can't delete a single node or a list of nodes.

In the question "[Can I delete nodes of a given content type with Drush?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/34044/28275)" I found 2 answers talking about the command `drush node_delete <nid>` but I can't find this command.

I found in a [discussion about node_delete()](https://api.drupal.org/comment/6299#comment-6299) some code using eval to accomplish this task, but it is using eval:

```
drush php-eval "global \$user; \$user = user_load(1); node_delete(nid);"
```

In case that there doesn't exist a functionality implemented to accomplish this, what is the better way to implement this functionality: in the [Drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) module or create a new module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the [Drush Entity module](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_entity), then you may run `drush entity-delete node 123` to delete nid 123 from your site.

**EDIT:** If somebody need to use the `drush entity-delete` command, should use the dev version of the module: https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_entity/releases/7.x-5.x-dev

Comment: thanks greg, you always helping with the drush stuffs ;-)

Comment: I found a bug inside the drush entity module who don't allow the deletion of nodes, I will commit the patch later.

Comment: You can found the issue and the patch in https://www.drupal.org/node/2756071#comment-11339679

Comment: The patch was submitted, if somebody need to use the `drush entity-delete` command should use at this moment the dev version of the Drush Entity module https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_entity/releases/7.x-5.x-dev

Answer (score 7):

Finally I create my own module named `drush_delete`

Inside the `drush_delete.drush.inc` file put this code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * The Drush Delete drush commands.
 */

/**
* Implements hook_drush_command().
*/
function drush_delete_drush_command() {
  $items['node-delete'] = array(
    'description' => dt("Delete nodes."),
    'aliases' => array('nd'),
    'arguments' => array(
      'nids' => dt('The nids of the nodes to delete'),
    ),
    'examples' => array(
      'drush node-delete 1' => dt('Delete the node with nid = 1.'),
      'drush node-delete 1 2 3' => dt('Delete the nodes with nid = 1, 2 and 3.'),

    ),
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Callback for the node-delete command
 */
function drush_drush_delete_node_delete() {
  $nids = func_get_args();
  $nids = array_filter($nids, 'is_numeric');
  $nids = array_map('intval', $nids);
  $nids = array_unique($nids);
  $nids = array_values($nids);
  $cant = count($nids);

  if ($cant > 0) {
    node_delete_multiple($nids);

    drush_print(dt("Deleted nodes:"));
    drush_print(implode(' ', $nids));
  }
  else {
    drush_set_error('DRUSH_ERROR_CODE', dt("You must enter at least one nid"));
  }
}
```

Install the module, run `drush cc drush` to clear the drush cache and use the command like this:

To delete a node use:

```
drush node-delete 1
drush nd 1
```

To delete multiple nodes use:

```
drush node-delete 1 2 3
drush nd 1 2 3
```

You can found the command in this module:

https://github.com/adrian-cid/drush_commands

Answer (score 7):

IMHO the easiest way is with php-eval:

```
drush php-eval "node_delete_multiple(array(NODE_ID));"
```

...

```
drush php-eval "node_delete_multiple(array(34));"     // for node/34

drush php-eval "node_delete_multiple(array(34, 35));" // for node ids 34 and 35
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think that if you have a drush command you can add arguments and option that maybe are needed. And you can add validations in a easy way.

Comment: I love this answer.  No custom drush command needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete all nodes use the range() function as

> `drush php-eval "node_delete_multiple(range(1,3000));"`